# mdadm raid10 or nfs performance issues?

Tags: linux, performance, raid, nfs, mdadm

I have a fresh mdadm RAID10 device which is healthy, built from 4 x 7200rpm SATA 3 drives:

```
# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid10] [raid1] 
md2 : active raid10 sdc3[5] sda3[4] sdb3[1] sdd3[3]
      3885267968 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
```

(There are 2 other mdadm devices, but md2 is the relevant one)

On top of md2 is an ext4 filesystem, created with:

```
mkfs.ext4 -m0 -L bups -b 4096 -E stride=8,stripe-width=32 /dev/md2
```

This has horrible performance when using it as a backup target over NFS. With a single client writing, I see figures like this, with ~30% to 50% I/O wait in `top`:

```
Device:            tps    MB_read/s    MB_wrtn/s    MB_read    MB_wrtn
sda             197.00         0.00         1.07          0          1
sdb             189.00         0.00         1.09          0          1
sdc             300.00         0.00         1.78          0          1
sdd             290.00         0.00         1.78          0          1
md2             785.00         0.00         2.86          0          2
```

Load Average is high:

```
# uptime
 11:40:38 up 21:21,  1 user,  load average: 9.90, 9.18, 8.92
```

Using `dd` shows decent performance:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/bup/test.dd bs=4096 count=1024000
1024000+0 records in
1024000+0 records out
4194304000 bytes (4.2 GB) copied, 18.7801 s, 223 MB/s
```

The connectivity is gigabit all the way. This is CentOS 6.2 x64 on a brand-new HP DL160 Gen8 with 16gb RAM, supposed to be a dedicated backup target, but not with this kind of performance.

***EDIT***

The controller is a HP B120i in SATA AHCI mode.

`/etc/exports` on the server:

```
/bup/phdv   172.31.42.30(rw,no_root_squash)
```

`/etc/fstab` extract on the client (also CentOS 6.4 x64):

```
svr-bup1.example.com:/bup/pronto    /mnt/bup    nfs soft    0 0
```

***EDIT 2***

Relevant information from `/proc/mounts`:

```
svr-bup1.example.com:/bup/pronto /mnt/bup2 nfs4 rw,relatime,vers=4,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,soft,proto=tcp6,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::240,minorversion=0,local_lock=none,addr=2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::210 0 0
```

Comment: You have no write cache... That's why. Is there a RAID controller in the server?

Comment: Also, can you share your NFS export and mount options?

Comment: @ewwhite Thanks for the comments - I'm writing nearly 100gb of data, so I don't think a write cache would make a difference with that much data? I'll edit the post with the export and mount details. FWIW, this server is replacing a Synology NAS performing the same task (backups, mounted via NFS) and it works fine, so it has to be something wrong on this host.

Comment: @ewwhite You made me think about comparing the Synology exports to mine - the Synology has `no_wdelay` enabled for the share. Adding that to mine has reduced the load significantly down to between 1 and 2, the TPS in iostat has reduced to <4 for each block device, and write speeds seem to have increased (although iostat says 0.00MB/s for each block dev). I think that may be the issue, although I don't understand it fully. Would having a write cache have negated the impact from `wdelay`?

Comment: Write cache on the RAID controller would benefit synchronous writes from an NFS client... Otherwise, your client will be waiting on write confirmation to the 7200 RPM disks rather than a low-latency cache.

Comment: I think I'll have to add the FBWC to the B120i, or a P420 to the server. If you want to post something about the WC as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: Assuming the client is running linux please post the the contents of the client's `/proc/mounts` (just the line with the NFS mount) to see the negotiated r/w sizes and other options. Also, have a look at `nfsstat` and `nfsiostat` (on the client) for oddities. `dd` may be a WTF?-tester but a real FS benchmarking tool like iozone may help. If you want to get adventurous give ZFS a try.

Comment: @MarkWagner I actually did originally have ZFS (using ZoL) and saw similar performance issues. I thought it was just ZoL, but thinking about it now, NFS is the common component. Updated question with `/proc/mounts` too, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

On server increasing `RPCNFSDCOUNT` number in `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server` may help;
on client(s) it may be worth trying smaller `rsize` and `wsize` values...